# How do you get the user role of the currently logged in user in Opencart?

Tags: opencart, user-roles

I wanted to get the user role id of the currently logged in user in Opencart for a required tweak on the listings of products. I could try to dig deep into opencart to see but hoping someone can save me time.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
$this->customer->getCustomerGroupId()
```

Which will return the value you want

Comment: Thank you for answering, I actually figured it out myself but I appreciate it that you answered it :)